# Have one page "normal" while using twocolumn documentclass option

Tags: latex

I'm using this configuration in my Latex document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape, twocolumn, 10pt]{article}
```

I'm using `twocolumn` because I want to have two columns on every page. But now I want to have one page (only one) with only one column (as if I didn't use the `twocolumn` option) and have the remainder of the document with two columns.

Answer (score 15):

You can issue `\onecolumn` which will force a page break and start typesetting with the usual one column.  When you are finished, issue `\twocolumn`, which will issue anothe page break and resume typesetting with two columns.

If you don't want page breaks, look at [Frank Mittelbach's `multicol` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/multicol).

There's more Latex expertise at [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) than here, these days.

Comment: Learned something new, +1 for \onecolumn

Comment: @Pranasas - multicol does support page-wide floats.  If you want column-wide floats (which are somewhat unusual in typesetting), take a look at Mittelbash's answer at tex.sx, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57750/175